# Index was outside the bounds of the array C#.net

Tags: c#

```
int i = 0;
string[] AbDates = new string[5];

private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    string dt = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dt))
    { 
    }
    else
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor == Color.Red)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Do you  want to UnMark this ?", "UnMark", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.No)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
                dt = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
                AbDates = AbDates.Where(val => val != dt).ToArray();
                i--;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Do you  want to Mark this As Absent?", "Absent", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.No)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                dt = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
                //MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
                AbDates[i] = dt;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here is my code..
I have an array with size[5]. I added 5 values into this array and then removed the values. Now my array have only one value. If I add another value to this array it shows the error Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: Use List Instead of array

Comment: Please format your code properly

Comment: you should have modified your [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945303/index-was-outside-the-bounds-of-the-array-c-sharp), instead of posting a new one with code

Comment: also, please post only relevant portion of your code, so that others don't have to waste hours figuring out your logic and all, besides, this is something you could have debugged easily

Answer (score 0):

### My Code is not exact correct but this helps you a little to try using this from list

Try This

```
int i = 0;
List<string> AbDates = new List<string>();
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
string dt = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dt))
{ 
}
else
{
if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor == Color.Red)
{
if (MessageBox.Show("Do you  want to UnMark this ?", "UnMark", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.No)
{
}
else
{
dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
dt = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
AbDates.AddRange(AbDates.Where(val => val != dt).ToList());
i--;
}
}
else
{
if (MessageBox.Show("Do you  want to Mark this As Absent?", "Absent", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.No)
{
}
else
{
dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
dt = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
//  MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
AbDates.Add(dt);
i++;
}
}
}
```

Comment: an error shows in AddRange(dt); string doesnot contain a defenition for 'Addrange'

Comment: Use Add() in place of AddRange()

Comment: No.. its not working..

Comment: Now i edited try with this

Answer (score 0):

```
AbDates = AbDates.Where(val => val != dt).ToArray();
```

You are creating a new array here, which is smaller than your original one (provided the value of dt was in the old one).

Like Co. Aden said, why not use a List?